# How to chain rxjs observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm currently building an Angular header component which makes use of [the CDK's Breakpoint Observer](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api#BreakpointObserver) to return a string of "mobile", "desktop", or "tablet" according to which breakpoint is currently active.

I then have a service which uses an RXJS behaviour subject to keep track of which NavLink Id (string value) the user clicked on last.

I'd like to use both the active breakpoint and linkID returned by the service in a single piece of logic like this:

```js
    this.breakpoints$ = this.breakpointObserver
    .observe([Breakpoint.SmallAndBelow, Breakpoint.Medium, Breakpoint.Large])
    .subscribe(({ breakpoints }) => {
      this.activeBreakpoint =
        breakpoints[Breakpoint.Large] === true
          ? 'desktop'
          : breakpoints[Breakpoint.Medium] === true
          ? 'tablet'
          : 'mobile';
    });
    
    this.$headerServiceSub = this.headerService.selectedLinkId.subscribe((link) => {
      if (this.headerService.previousSelectedLinkId === this.hostAttrId && !link && this.activeBreakpoint === 'mobile') {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.elRef.nativeElement.focus();
        }, 100);
      }
      this.selectedLink = link;
    });
```

This code does work as expected in the browser however when unit testing Jest reports **"Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"**

I believe this is because both the breakpoint observer and the BehaviorSubject used to store the linkID are asynchronous so `this.activeBreakpoint` will not necessarily have a value when the `this.headerService.selectedLinkId.subscribe` method is run. If this is the case is there a way I can chain the two methods to ensure `this.activeBreakpoint` always has a value?

Comment: Maybe have a look at combineLatest?

Comment: It looks like combineLatest has been deprecated. There is a combineLatestWith which seems to have replaced it. I'm not quite sure how to apply it to the code above though. `this.$headerServiceSub` and `this.breakpoint$` do not have pipe methods which from the documentation it sounds like you need to place the combineLatestWith within. If someone could answer with an example that would be really helpful.

Comment: It's not deprecated - just certain signatures are (it wants an array with Observables now)

Answer (score 0):

There are many options on chaining observable, you can look at here https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators#join-creation-operators